# Pause previous audio when new audio is played

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

When user clicks on an item, I am dynamically adding a unique audio element like this and playing an audio.

```
      let sound = document.createElement("audio");
      sound.id = "audio" + e.target.id;
      app.audioBeingPlayed = sound.id;
      sound.controls = "controls";
      sound.src = selectedVoice[0][1].sample;
      sound.type = "audio/mpeg";
      sound.play()
```

Before doing this I am checking if an audio is already being played and want to pause that audio.

I tried doing this

```
  if(app.audioBeingPlayed) {
    $('audio #'+ app.audioBeingPlayed).pause()
  }
```

before the code above.

When one item is clicked, it plays an audio. But when another item is clicked it gives an error saying

> $(...).pause is not a function

**I just want to pause the audio being played and play the new audio as created in the code in the first block.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your code from

```
if(app.audioBeingPlayed) {
    $('audio #'+ app.audioBeingPlayed).pause() // $('audio #'+ app.audioBeingPlayed) is not the audio object.
  }
```

to this

```
....
....

app.audioBeingPlayed = e.target.id; // set the correct target id.
if(app.audioBeingPlayed) {
    $('#'+ app.audioBeingPlayed).pause() // $('#'+ app.audioBeingPlayed) is the audio object so play/pause will work.


//or directly use the id to pause.
$('#'+ e.target.id).pause() 
  }
```